# ios keep UITableViewCell layout after scroll

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have a `UITableView` with data fetched from the a web api (which is also paginated and searchable). Each cell is a custom `UITableViewCell` that I made and contains a data object. The cell has two states, normal and added.

Normal has one "add" button to add the data object to an selectedObjects array. The added mode is similar but with the content being pushed to the right for a few pixels in order to display a "remove" button.

When I add one item to the array, I animate the cell to move to the right and show the remove button. Now my problem:

When I scroll (or when I make a new search) I can't seem to know how to reset the cell to the "added" state.

What I have tried:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let myCustomCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyCellIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as MyCustomCell
    let dataObject = fromApiArray[indexPath.row]
    myCustomCell.dataObject = dataObject
    if selectedObjects.contains(dataObject) {
        myCustomCell.setToAddedState = true //flag to use inside the cell code in prepareForReuse or wherever I don't really know...
        myCustomCell.moveCellToRight() //just another way I tried. calling the method that animates the cell from the tableviewcontroller... (sounds silly I guess)
    }
    return myCustomCell
}
```

I tried calling the cell `moveCellToRight()`, but I guess the cell is drawn after returning it here with the "normal" state.
Since this didn't help, I went and set a boolean (setToAddedState) and tried making use of `prepareForReuse` and `layoutSubviews` methods inside the cell, but doesn't help either.

Moreover, some cells actually change to the "added" state but randomly. If I print the dataObject within `prepareForReuse` it prints properly. So my only thing missing here is how to make the cell display the correct state.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: when dequeue, the reuse cell will preserve the previous state. so you should set the cell's appearance base on each state, not the default state and added state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few things you're missing here:

Firstly, you have to remember that `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` does just that. It reuses a cell which has already been created. If the cell is not in the state you want it to be, (i.e added) you need to make sure it is in this state before it is displayed.

Secondly, if you look at the documentation for `prepareForReuse`

> this method is invoked just before the object is returned from the UITableView method dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:

which means setting a flag after dequeing to be checked in `prepareForReuse` will be too late. `prepareForReuse` should be used to reset the cell to its default state.

Lastly, if your cell needs any specific variable state to be set - whether that be data, layout, styling etc - you should do this in your delegate's `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` implementation.

In your code, it would make sense for you to set the "added" state and the cell's layout directly from `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` as you are attempting to do. Setting a flag is not the way to do it. You should have a `setAdded:` method on your cell which shows the added state immediately and your `moveCellToRight` method should also layout the cell as you wish it to be immediately. There is no point in animating this as the cell is not visible at this point.

Also, calling a method to set the cell's layout from `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is not silly, it's exactly what you should do!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But something's wrong. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't (more the times it doesn't, both on scrolling or making a new search which refreshes the whole table with new data). Now the only thing I have is a method that I call to move the cell to the right (no animation of course, and as you pointed), I see the frame being updated (printing the frame to the console) but the view is most times with the default layout. I'm sure I'm missing something else.

Comment: Hmm, I'm sorry but it sounds like this is problem with the layout code for your cell. The way I described is the standard documented way of doing this. I'm afraid I can't help much more without seeing the layout code of your cell.

Comment: Perhaps either edit your original post to add the relevant cell code, or link a gist with the code in one of these comments.

Comment: Thanks. Will do that. Maybe before that I'll create a sample example project with an api I could share. If I still have the same problems I'll post the github page with it. Btw the only thing in the code I'm doing is changing the uiview frame with an offset of x pixels.

Comment: Thanks. I got it working. What I did? I am reusing the cells. In prepareForReuse method I'm resetting to default layout, and then in the tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath I have the condition to set to the added state. I have one problem though. I tested with a backgound color and it changes nicely scrolling out and back in. But changing a view's frame only works sometimes. I scroll violently to the original cell and it's not good. Smoothly, it displays the proper frame. Any hint? Should I provide you with code?

Comment: I'm afraid it's hard for me to guess what's going wrong with your frame setting code unless I see it. Personally, when changing layout I would use Auto Layout and either switch constraints' priorities or change constraints' constant values. This is Apple's recommended way of controlling layout these days.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. When animating I change the frame, when setting the state for reuse I reset the constraint constant. :) thanks for the help.